# SQLite Plugin for Android version 4.0 - 4.4.+?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

When I am looking for SQLite plugin for android phonegap, I found for versions 4.2 and 4.3 with SDK API 17 and 18, but it is not stable below 4.2 and above 4.4. Can any one suggest a SQLite plugin for Android from version 4.0 SDK API 14 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using with big satisfaction till now

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Comment: I reviewed the same link. But it says that Problem with Android 4.4. and Issue buiding with Android SDK < 16.

Comment: I've used the same plugin. but I hadn't had any problems with Android 4.4.

Comment: Sorry this is slightly off topic but given Cordova is about crossplatform support I wanted to chime in to say I found this plugin has saved my bacon!  I had to port the websql app over from iOS/Android to WP8 and the MSOpenTech WebSQL to Sqlite one had serious reliability issues when throwing a lot of data at it... randomly worked which made it even harder to debug.  Swapped for this plugin and works a charm first time on WP8.  Great to hear it's working on Android4.4 as we need a great plugin like this for cross platform support.